# DropdownButton updating with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, provider, flutter-state

When i choose item in the below list, it does not change. If i click the others,then nothing happens.
How can i change this value both firestore and UI ?
I know, i need to update `value: constantValue,` this code, but how i can do that with provider?

Here, button:

```
Widget dropdownButton(BuildContext context) {
String constantValue = "League Of Legends";
return DropdownButton(
    value: constantValue,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      context.read<PostProvider>().postCategory = newValue;
    },
    items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
      );
    }).toList());
```

}

and also provider:

```
     String _postCategory;

     String get postCategory => _postCategory;

  set postCategory(String value) {
    _postCategory = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This question needs elaboration.  What code is updating Firestore? Are you using `ChangeNotifierProvider`? (It needs to wrap what you you want changed -- or are you expecting to update Firestore and then refresh from a stream subscription?)

Comment: The `DropdownButton` has a hard-coded value: `value: constantValue,` -- but that needs to be the value from `PostProvider`, like: `context.watch<PostProvider>().postCategory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include something to write FireBase in the code path.  Provider doesn't magically do that for you.  However, you *can* have various providers or widgets wake up on that notify_listeners() call.

Comment: i have already included but it still does not change